# Simple MySQL query to associate images with events

Tags: mysql

In my small application, I have events that can have multiple images associated with them.

For example, the event "snowboarding", may have three images associated with it.

**Here are my tables:**

```
Events
   event_id  title

Event_Images
   event_image_id   image_src   time_uploaded
```

Here is the query that I am currently using:

```
SELECT * FROM Events, Event_Images 
   WHERE Events.event_id = Event_Images.event_id
```

It results in the following data:

```
[
    {
        "event_id": "67",
        "title": "Setting up the UGS App!",
        "event_image_id": "64",
        "image_src": "uploads/50f47bce35d4f.jpg",
        "time_uploaded": "2013-01-14 16:42:41"
    },
    {
        "event_id": "67",
        "title": "Setting up the UGS App!",
        "event_image_id": "92",
        "image_src": "uploads/49f4709eppdl.jpg",
        "time_uploaded": "2013-02-14 12:44:43"
    }
]
```

However, this seems redundant to me. The data structure I imagine would be the least redundant would appear like so:

```
[
    {
        "event_id": "67",
        "title": "Setting up the UGS App!",
        "event_image_id": "64",
        "images": [
            {
                "image_src": "uploads/50f47bce35d4f.jpg",
                "time_uploaded": "2013-01-14 16:42:41"
            },
            {
                "image_src": "uploads/49f4709eppdl.jpg",
                "time_uploaded": "2013-02-14 12:44:43"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I imagine that either the current way I am doing it is correct, or there is a method that will result in a less redundant result from my query.

Pardon my ignorance if this seems like a simple question.

Any references or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a loop for the (query) output in PHP, then?

Comment: Do you mean to take the data that is returned and then organize it in the way that I want to?

Comment: Yep. All you will need is to loop the data once in php and insert the elements in a new array. Let me know if you want an example and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm working on it right now, thank you for your advice. I was asking more from a performance perspective if this redundant looking data was a bad thing and if it could be organized differently coming from the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to inhan I have my answer-- use php to format the data after it is returned. With this information, I just wrote a reuseable function:

```
function merge_data($data, $merge_key, $merge_prop, $merge_data) {
    /* build an array of the merge data arranged by the merge key */
    $associated_data_keys = array();
    foreach($data as $value) {
        $grouped_merge_data = array(); // group together the merge data
        foreach($merge_data as $merge_value) {
            $grouped_merge_data[$merge_value] = $value[$merge_value];
        }
        if (empty($associated_data_keys[$value[$merge_key]])) {
            $associated_data_keys[$value[$merge_key]] = array();
        }
        array_push($associated_data_keys[$value[$merge_key]], $grouped_merge_data);
    }

    /* remove duplicate data values */
    $existing_keys = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value[$merge_key], $existing_keys)) {
            array_push($existing_keys, $value[$merge_key]);
        } else {
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }

    /* remove merge data properties */
    foreach($merge_data as $value) {
        foreach($data as $key => $data_value) {
            unset($data[$key][$value]);
        }
    }

    /* put our data from the first statement back into our data set */
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        /* assign our data set at this value at the merge property to the corresponding merged data */
        $data[$key][$merge_prop] = $associated_data_keys[$value[$merge_key]];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Use in this case:

```
$events = merge_data($events, 'event_id', 'images', array('event_image_id', 'image_src', 'time_uploaded'));
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL returns matching rows. It doesn't return a hierarchy of data from a RBMS. You would need two queries to achieve the data structure you desire -- one to select the event, then one to select the event images. Then append the event images to your "images" array in the event object.

Comment: I have tried this, however. Performance is really bad, especially if there are hundreds of events. Running queries in a loops didn't work for me when my user base scaled

Comment: So you would recommend that I keep the query the way that I currently have it and arrange the data with PHP after it is returned? I guess i'm asking, is there anything bad (in terms of processing power, memory required) about this much redundant data being returned?